# disable lookup for .htaccess file in subdirectories via .htaccess in root

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Is it possible to disable lookup for .htaccess file in subdirectories, when I know I will only need my .htaccess in root directory?
I know it can be done with "AllowOverride None" when you have access to the server configuration file. But can I do this with my .htaccess file in root as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. It must be done inside a `<Directory>` directive, which can only exist inside core configuration files.